# I am facing issue for selenium webdriver script for Goibibo site city selection using xpath/css selector

Tags: selenium, webdriver

While selecting city from site using `xpath/css` selector facing issue let me know solution

```
List<WebElement> frm=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("html body div#gi_midcontent.col-md-12.col-sm-12.col-xs-12.pad0 div#gi_mid_in div#viewContainer div#flights-home-view.homeContainer.col-md-12.col-sm-12.col-xs-12.myPropDisplay div.homeContainerInner div#searchWidgetNew.blueBg.homeWidgetWrap.posRel form#gi_search div#searchWidgetCommon div.formWrap.padT15 div#source_st.fl_shAutosgBox.col-md-5.col-sm-5.col-xs-12.autoSuggestBox.marginB10 input#gi_source_st.form-control.inputTxtLarge.fromTxt.posRel"));
```

Comment: And how can we help you if we don't know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things.

1. Go through the selenium document here.http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp
2. Read on how to use different locator strategy to identity particular locator.
3. Don't ask the question just because something is not working,spend some time on that.
4. Visit this page to understand how to ask question so that you can get answers.

The reason I have mentioned above point is you css locator looks pathetic, also the locator you are trying to identify has both name and id, and if you now how to use locator you could have figure that out.

Comment: actually the issue is when i am trying to read city on Goibibo site using List<WebElement> Val=driver.findelements(By.xpath("  ")); for(WebElement sel:Val){ System.out.println(sel.getText());}  so can you please tell me how to get that all city values it will helpful.as per your ans you know very well this ,,

Comment: Gaurang Shah can you please check for goibibo site for city selection function in selenium

Answer (score 0):

The selector specified in the problem mixed id and class. However, taking a look at the website, the suggested city list is not offered as a group of input elements but fetched from AJAX.

Sending GET query with Postman tool on this URL and you can get JSON data with a list of objects. The property of json["data"]["r"][index]["xtr"]["cn"] seems a string of "CityName". This API does not require authentication so it can be fetched with Java HttpClient, too.

```
https://voyager.goibibo.com/api/v1/flights_search/find_node_by_name_v2/?search_query=hint&limit=10
```

The sample result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "r": [
      {
        "s_sc": 5055001,
        "xtr": {
          "cn": "Beica",
          "cid": "1918715907401915921",
          "cc": "ET",
          "dis_type": "ldis",
          "ar": 0,
          "eid": "7717797727439208389",
          "cnt_n": "Ethiopia",
          "cnt_id": "1871100673297067773",
          "dis": 0
        },
        "iata": "BEI",
        "n": "Beica Airport",
        "mt": "Beica Airport ### Beica",
        "t": "airport",
        "_id": "7717797727439208389",
        "ct": {
          "_id": "1918715907401915921",
          "n": "Beica"
        }
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Please replace "hint" with your query string, for example, a letter to start with. Also take the note that (page) limit could not be greater than 50 in one query.